# Configuring cloud with minimum configuration on Oracle VirtualBox using OpenStack software

Tags: cloud, virtualbox, openstack

I have a college project to configure cloud on Oracle VirtualBox having minimum configuration as possible using open stack. Could you please tell me, if its possible to configure all nodes in a single machine, or do we need anymore. Also it would be very helpful if you help me find out what exactly to install for setting up Compute and Networking nodes, and how exactly would they interact.

The Machine I'm using is a basic laptop having 4 GB RAM size, having intel i3 core and 64-bit configuration

Comment: With that hardware.. I don't know what kind of cluster are you going to create... but is going to be very very small with an awful performance.

Comment: Yes, I understand but its just a college project just for understanding purpose and nothing more than that. I just need an idea about from where and how to start. Need the help in implementation practically, maybe a small scale demo.

Answer (score 1):

you can use devstack. OpenStack used for development purpose, refer this link https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack for more details, but as OscarAkaElvis suggested it will not be useful to a great extent.